# How to get my bitcoin back

Tags: blockchain, revert-transaction

I have copied and sent bitcoin to the address that I have found on my blockchain wallet only to find out its not mine. So is there anyway I can get my bitcoin back?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get it back.  Once it is sent and confirmed into a block, it is permanent.
Best hope is that the address belongs to someone and they send it back thinking it was a mistake.

Sorry